# 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddPolicyHandler'

Tags: c#, azure-functions, .net-5, azure-durable-functions, polly

I am getting error in my .NET 5.0 framework Azure durable function project in VS2019

> 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddPolicyHandler' and the best extension  method overload 'PollyHttpClientBuilderExtensions.AddPolicyHandler(IHttpClientBuilder, IAsyncPolicy)' requires a receiver of type 'IHttpClientBuilder'

**.csproj**

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityModel" Version="4.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.15.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask" Version="2.5.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.13" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**Startup.cs**

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Polly;
using Polly.Extensions.Http;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
namespace Itel.DeliveryOrchestration
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddHttpClient()
                .AddPolicyHandler(GetRetryPolicy());
        }

        private IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> GetRetryPolicy()
        {
            return HttpPolicyExtensions 
                .HandleTransientHttpError()
                .OrResult(msg => msg.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                .WaitAndRetryAsync(2, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt)));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Error is correct [source](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.Http/DependencyInjection/HttpClientFactoryServiceCollectionExtensions.cs,23) `AddHttpClient` with no arguments returns `IServiceCollection` while `AddPolicyHandler` applies to `IHttpClientBuilder`. You will need to use a named client

Comment: @Nkosi Thank you. Now it looks silly :)

Answer (score 4):

As I can see (based on the provided code sample) you have used the wrong Polly -  HttpClient integration nuget package

```
using Polly.Extensions.Http;

builder.Services.AddHttpClient()
                .AddPolicyHandler(GetRetryPolicy());
```

- The [`Polly.Extensions.Http`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Polly.Extensions.Http) is deprecated and not updated anymore
- You should prefer to use [`Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly/) package instead

Answer (score 2):

Posting suggestion provided by [@Nkosi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5233410/nkosi) in the comments as an answer so that it will be helpful for other community members who face similar kind of issues.

> `AddHttpClient` with no arguments returns `IServiceCollection` while `AddPolicyHandler` applies to `IHttpClientBuilder`. You will need to use a named client

```
public static IServiceCollection AddHttpClient(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    if (services == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(services));
    }

    //...
```

Referenced source code [HttpClientFactoryServiceCollectionExtensions](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.Http/DependencyInjection/HttpClientFactoryServiceCollectionExtensions.cs,23)